# asyncpg DataError: invalid input for query argument expected str, got int

Tags: python, postgresql, asyncpg

I admittedly don't understand how asyncpg's codecs work, but it seems to work counter to how I'd expect:

```
import asyncio
import asyncpg


async def main():
    conn = await asyncpg.connect('postgresql://postgres@localhost/test')

    print(await conn.fetchval("select $1", 'a'))  # this works: prints 'a'
    print(await conn.fetchval("select $1", 1))  # invalid input for query argument $1: 1 (expected str, got int)

asyncio.run(main())
```

It seems asyncpg wants the parameter to always be a string, but I want it to be an int. Why does this fail?

Comment: What if you do `await conn.fetchval("select $1::int", 1)`? See [DatatypeMismatchError](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/issues/1057).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Specify postgresql type `int`

Using `conn.fetchval("select $1::int", 1)` might solve your issue.

We can see an example of parameter type set to int [here](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html#asyncpg.prepared_stmt.PreparedStatement.get_parameters).